# Visagroup doesn't exist

Tags: visas, uk, applications, vfs-global

[image]
Doing UK visa (Tier 4 General Student) from Malaysia. After the document upload supposedly should direct me to making appointment. Stuck at this 'Visagroup does not exist' for hours. Does anyone know what does this suppose to mean?

Comment: Based on your description, this appears to be an error on the website. It is very unlikely that anybody here can help you with that. If this is issue preventing you from submitting your application, I suggest you contact VFS directly for support.

Comment: @ChrisH I am not sure whether it's due to website error or not. Apparently, a friend of mine does not face the same problem. Have not heard back from VFS. I need to book an appointment ASAP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about a website error requiring resolution via VFS Support